# Automatic formatting of amount in field text box with comma for the last 2 digits

Tags: c#, winforms

How can i make a comma for the last 2 digits of number . Instead of dot, ill use comma

What should be the format ? should i use regex for every text change because it might affect performance

I have a code but it gave me

```
 private void txtNumNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double value;

        if (double.TryParse(txtNumNo.Text, out value))
        {
            txtNumNo.Text = String.Format("{0:0,00}", value); // 12,345.67
        }
        else
        {
            // Some code to handle the bad input (not parsable to double)
        }
    }
```

So it should be like example i input
5 0 7, it will automatically 5,07 for every text change
10068 = 100,68

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better use a [`NumericUpDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx) control and set the property [`DecimalPlaces`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.decimalplaces.aspx) to two.

For getting the desired separator you should change the culture of the UI thread to whatever has the desired separator (e.g. german).